# EF6 - add objects to tables dynamicaly

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm new around here (I know this site for long but it's my first time actually asking somehting).

Components that I'm using: - EF6, Devexpress XtraGrid

Ok... so, what I want is to kind of do this,
I have 1 form with multiple tables, and which I will have to be able to add and delete from each's NavigationBar.

I know how to do it, I just need a way to skip the select case.

Here's some code,

```
Private Sub ListChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs)
    If e.ListChangedType = System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemAdded Then
        Dim bList As BindingList(Of Object) = TryCast(sender, BindingList(Of Object))
        Dim m As Object = bList.LastOrDefault()
        If m IsNot Nothing Then
            Select Case _curentPageIndex
                Case 0 : db.GESTARM.Add(m)
                Case 1 : 'Other table add
                Case 2 : 'Other table add
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to do with that is kind of this:

```
Private Sub ListChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs)
    If e.ListChangedType = System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemAdded Then
        Dim bList As BindingList(Of Object) = TryCast(sender, BindingList(Of Object))
        Dim m As Object = bList.LastOrDefault()
        'somehow get the table (type) of the entry through the m object
        If m IsNot Nothing Then
            db.<Table>.Add(m)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So instead of writing every add for each case, I just had to do something like that.
Is it possible or am I going to stick with the select case?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if my english is bad (I'm not native).

EDIT 1:
as Mark mentioned in a comment we could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675564/in-entity-framework-how-do-i-add-a-generic-entity-to-its-corresponding-dbset-wi) in C#
but in VB it doesn't work...

```
Public Class GenericRepository(Of T)
Implements IDisposable
Friend context As GestProGest1Entities
Friend dbSet As Entity.DbSet(Of T) ' Gives error on T "Type argument 'T' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'TEntity'"

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    If context IsNot Nothing Then
        context.Dispose()
        context = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub New(context As GestProGest1Entities)
    Me.context = context
    Me.dbSet = context.Set(Of T)() ' Gives error on T "Type argument 'T' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'TEntity'"
End Sub

Public Overridable Sub Insert(entity As T)
    dbSet.Add(entity)
    context.SaveChanges()
End Sub
End Class
```

Any ideas how to do this in VB?

EDIT 2:
Ok, so I got it working like this

```
Public Class GenericRepository(Of T As Class)
```

now my problem is how to get the type from the object

```
Private Sub ListChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs)
    If e.ListChangedType = System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemAdded Then
        Dim bList As BindingList(Of Object) = TryCast(sender, BindingList(Of Object))
        Dim m As Object = bList.LastOrDefault()
        Dim myType As Type = m.GetType()
        Dim table As New GenericRepository(Of myType)(db) 'Doesn't accept myType here...
        table.Insert(m)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You english is good and your question is well explained, so job well done. This question has come up a couple times before,http://stackoverflow.com/q/28364376/1158842, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5295554/1158842, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8138070/1158842, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17879206/1158842. Do these address your question?

Comment: Well, I guess I have to stick with select case from what I read from those posts, EF doesn't like dyncamic stuff...
Thanks for the help anyway, and if someone has any idea how to make this in a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: you could add the entities on DataSet level, however you'll have to do a lot of handling yourself then.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I can't use DataSet on this project, it would be easy to just bind the grid to that (DevExpress makes wonders with DataSets) but I just can't use it here sorry, thanks for the sugestion tho.

Comment: What is the type of the variable `db`?

Comment: Is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944527/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-method-for-adding-items-to-a-entity-framework) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675564/in-entity-framework-how-do-i-add-a-generic-entity-to-its-corresponding-dbset-wi) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mark yes, it should be exactly that, except VB doesn't like that `context.Set<T>`

Comment: Edited the post to give some more info with @Mark 's help

Comment: I think perhaps I sent you down the wrong path because I didn't fully understand your question.  Since you don't know `T`, I think you would have to use reflection to use the generic repository from that example.  However, it seems that `DbContext` has a [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%28System.Type%29) method that takes the type as a parameter, so perhaps all you need in your initial attempt (2nd code block) is something like `db.Set(m.GetType()).Add(m)`?

Comment: @Mark, waw, didn't think it was really that simple, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Mark's help I finally got this working.

```
Private Sub ListChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs)
  If e.ListChangedType = System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemAdded Then
      Dim m As Object = sender(sender.count - 1)
      db.Set(m.GetType()).Add(m)
  End If 
End Sub
```

Thanks for everyone's help!